# Possible to know the publisher in Redis

Tags: java, android, redis, publish-subscribe, jedis

I am building an Android application that requires me to subscribe to multiple channels. I am using Jedis 2.4.2 for connecting to a Redis server for the same. I am using a separate client for every channel. The problem is that since Jedis subscription is not thread-safe, I am having trouble unsubscribing. As a workaround, I was thinking of a server-side program that keeps listening for messages from different clients on a dedicated channel and kills all subscriptions on receiving a request from them. For this, I need to identify the publisher of the request. Is there any way to accomplish this or a simpler way to execute the unsubscription task?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310551/subscribe-to-multiple-channels-with-same-thread-jedis